# variant of Heisenberg group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, definition, lie-groups, heisenberg-group

If $A$ is skew-symmetric matrix of $M_n$, it seems to me that $G=\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the product
$$
(s,t) \cdot (s', t') 
= \bigg(s + s', t + t' + \frac{1}{2} \langle s, A s'\rangle\bigg)
$$
is a group. Here $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the canonical scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Out by curiosity, does it have a name? Is it studied somewhere ?

Comment: Try searching for "generalized Heisenberg group". That has been used to describe groups of this type, but I think it has several other possible definitions.

Comment: By putting $A$ into normal form it follows that this group is the direct product of a usual Heisenberg group and $\mathbb R^m$ for some $m$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Isn't a central product of two ordinary Heisenberg groups (i.e. direct product with amalgamated centre) an example of this type? That has centre isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I meant a Heisenberg group of dimension $2m+1$ for some $m$, as at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Higher_dimensions, which as you say is a central product of $m$ copies of the $3$-dimensional one.

Comment: The normal form for skew symmetric matrices is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory. The only important invariant is the rank.